# Identify repetitive pattern in numeric vector in R with fuzzy search

Tags: r, algorithm, function

Imagine a vector of integers like so:

```
> rep(c(1,4,2),10)
[1] 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2
```

For us human beings it seems easy to identify the pattern 1 - 4 - 2 even without knowing the function how the vector was created. But how would you identify this pattern using R?

**Edit**

As this question was marked as a dupe I'm going to specify it a bit. The above example was an easy one to explain the idea. The main goal would be to identify more hidden patterns like `1 4 2 5 6 7 1 4 2 9 1 4 2 3 4 5 1 4 2` and also patterns that are approximately the same like `1 4 2 1 4 1.99 1 4 2 1.01 4 2 1 4.01 2`. What are the ideas to always Identify the pattern `1 4 2` in those cases?

Comment: What if there are other numbers also in the vector along with the repetitive patterns?

Comment: You mean something like `1 4 2 1 4 2 *5* 1 4 2`? Would be even better to still be able to identify the patterns. However as a first step I thought the example above might be easier.

Comment: Please, define what a `pattern` is. If you want to translate what a human mind might think is a `pattern` in a computer program, your research could last forever.

Comment: Yes, it is easier, but then you would ask for something along more difficult cases.

Comment: Pattern recognition can take on many forms you have to be specific in terms of the possible difficulty. So with `1 4 1 2 4 3 4 1 4 1 4 1 2 4 3 4 1 4 1 3` What kind of pattern is this in your opinion?

Comment: This should get you somewhere close to what you want I think? `x <- rep(c(1,4,2),10); which.max(sapply(1:floor(length(x)/2), function(y) all(rep(x[1:y], floor(length(x) / y)) == x)))`. Finds the shortest length substring that is repeating itself.

Comment: For your example, `len = 0; is_patt = FALSE; while (len <= length(x)/2 & !is_patt){len = len + 1; is_patt = identical(x, rep(x[1:len], length.out=length(x)))}` works, but it's obvious that you want something fancier that you haven't specified here...

Comment: @nicola probably I'm looking exactly for this kind which a human mind would think is a pattern. But this would also probably involve much more research (maybe in topics like deep learning) as you said. For now I would define a pattern as "The smallest consecutive sequence of numbers that repeats over the vector". Examples: In `1 1 1 1 1` the pattern would be `1` and in `1 2 1 2 1 2` the pattern would be `1 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestions.
@PierreLafortune I think it' similar, but not quite a dupe, as Tyler wants to find "pattern groups". I'm not immediately seeing a pattern in your sequence example. Apart from the `1 4 1` that sometimes occurs in between the other elements. But it would be great to find also this hidden pattern.
@Frank and @Gopala find out the length of the pattern, which is already pretty helpful.

Comment: @Peter only the first @ in a comment is notified, fyi.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the subpattern must start at the beginning and repeat to the end of the input try it for a subpattern length of k = 1, 2, 3, ...   We have assumed that only patterns that are half the length of the input or less are to be considered:

```
for(k in seq_len(length(x)/2)) {
    pat <- x[1:k]
    if (identical(rep(pat, length = length(x)), x)) { 
         print(pat)
         break
    }
}
## [1] 1 4 2
```

**Note:** This was used as the input `x`:

```
x <- rep(c(1, 4, 2), 10)
```

Comment: This is a clever idea! It definitely finds a repetitive pattern if it starts from the beginning. And since it answers the original question I want to give you the check. But is this also possible for more advanced searches, such as the example from @PierreLafortune above? Like a "hidden" pattern? Or a "fuzzy" version of the pattern, such as `1 4 2 1 4 1.99 1 4 2 1.01 4 2 1 4.01 2`?

Comment: Preprocess `x` to remove any number that appears `m` times or less.   `m=1`  would work with your example.  So if we use `x <- x[x %in% names(table(x)[table(x) > m])]` and then apply algorithm it would work.

Comment: This would not quite do the trick. After this I get the sequence `1 4 2 1 4 1 4 2 4 2 1 2`. Of course applying the algorithm then would give me nothing as the first half of the sequence is not equal to the second one. Am I missing something? @G.Grothendieck

Comment: The assumption was that you have a repeititve sequence with insertions of non-repeating junk.  If you don't have that then of course it is inapplicable.  Another thing you can try is count the number of non-matching positions: `sapply(1:(length(x)/2), function(m) sum(rep(x[1:m], length = length(x)) != x))` and then inspect the ones with low count.  Obviously these simple approaches all have limitations but they are easy to do.

Comment: Also look at `seq_dist` in the stringdist package.